# calling a service layer method to my presentation layer

Tags: java

Ok I feel really dumb asking this but I seem to be missing something really simple here.  I have the following code in a class in my service layer -

```
public Items getItems(String category, float amount, String color,
            String type)
```

The code reads from a database and returns the results - I plan on placing it in a jframe.  Nice and simple.  But no matter how I call it from the jframe I get errors in eclipse that the code is wrong - either that their are illegal modifiers or such.  So obviously I am calling it completely wrong, so my stupid question is how do you call that method into a jframe?

For example - if I try to call it this way:

```
public Items getItems();
```

I get told that getItems is an illegal parameter.
If I call this.. Items getItems();  I am told its undefined

Comment: Do u really think we can answer this without guessing? You need to give us the exact error and preferably the code around the line that causes the error.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question as is.

Comment: You might as well have pasted `public static void Main(String[] args)` and said that "the trouble starts here". We need the actual code, not the method signature.

Comment: There *is* no code at this point other than a blank window - thats the point.  Its a blank window that is supposed to have a single thing in it.  A call to the method I referenced.

Comment: You really need to get a book about Java. If you don't know how to invoke methods in this language, how are you planning to write anything?

Comment: normally I have no problem with something this basic, it's been pissing me off for the last twenty minutes that I've been missing something I knew had to be elementary.  Ahh well. I probably shouldn't be coding on pain meds, but time waits for no man yadda yadda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you put some code up there, you are invoking the method wrong; what you have is not valid Java.

First you need to get an instance of your service.

`MyService service = new MyServiceImpl();`

I'm assuming your service is defined as an interface (`MyService`), with a class that implements the interface (`MyServiceImpl`).

then you invoke the method on the instance

`Items items = service.getItems(stuff);`

what you have

`public Items getItems();`

is some sort of hybrid between a method definition and a method invocation.

Comment: gah, an instance of the service, I knew I was forgetting something simple- thank you!